# A problem in division rings and Brauer group

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, tensor-products, division-algebras

Suppose that $D, E$ are two division rings in the Brauer group of $F$ ($Br(F)$), where $F$ is local field. Show that $D\otimes_FE$ is a division ring iff $([D:F],[E:F])=1$.

Comment: Dear user, What facts do you know about the Brauer groups of local fields?  It's hard to make concrete suggestions without knowing this, and perhaps knowing what text this question came from.  Regards,

Comment: A and B are central simple F-algebra

Comment: Dear user, Thanks for editing your question; I'll delete my previous comments.  However, you still haven't stated what you know about Brauer groups (in general, and for local fields in particular).    If you do this, it will make it easier to get helpful answers.  Regards,

Comment: I agree wholeheartedly with Matt E's comments (and he has been very patient and helpful; others might have just voted to close).  You could still do much more to help us help you: in what context is this "problem" being asked?  If it is coming from a text, which text?  If we knew that, someone who is so inclined could look in the textbook and craft an answer that makes sense *as an answer to the exercise in the text* (i.e., only uses material that has been covered earlier in the text).  Without this, it is anyone's guess as to what a helpful answer might be.

Comment: brauer group local field is equal Q/Z

Answer (score 3):

Some hints:

1) The implication $[D:F], [E:F]$ relatively prime implies $D \otimes_F E$ is a division algebra has nothing to do with $F$ being local: it is true (and is a very standard fact) for finite dimensional central division algebras over an arbitrary field.

Without knowing what your background in this subject is it will be hard to sketch out an answer that will necessarily be helpful to you, but here is one way to go that may or may not be accessible to you: you want to show that the **index** of $A := D \otimes_F E$ is equal to the product of the indices of $D$ and $E$.  Thus if $d = \sqrt{[D:F]}$ and $e = \sqrt{[E:F]}$, you want to show that the index of $A$ is $de$.  For this, it suffices to show that $A$ is not split by any field extension of degree prime to $d$ and is not split by any field extension of degree prime to $e$.  And that's easy: after making a field extension $L/K$ of degree prime to $d$, the period of $D_{/L}$ is still divisible by $d$, and the period of $E_{/L}$ is still prime to $d$...

2) Here you do need to use that the Brauer group of a local field is $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$.  I would also like to use that the period and index are equal in the Brauer group of a local field (which follows from the "standard fact" that the restriction map on Brauer groups induced by a degree $d$ extension of local fields is multiplication by $d$).  And if you know these things, the result is not hard: really we are saying something like: since $6$ and $4$ are not relatively prime, the order of $\frac{1}{6} + \frac{1}{4}$ in $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ is smaller than $24$.

Comment: Dear Pete, Probably $d$ should be $b$ near the end of the discussion of point (1).  Cheers,

Comment: @Matt: Thanks, but this typo was drowned out by a larger error...

Comment: Dear Pete, Ah, good (not that I'm glad there was an error, but I'm glad that I can now follow the argument, whereas I was a bit confused before!).  Actually, when thinking about this, I had only proved it for myself in the local fields case, so it's great that you've sketched the result more generally.  Cheers,